I can't reach 1ms precision in C#
i am writing a windows forms application that interacts with an external USB device, I need to be able to read/write from/to the device periodically with 1ms precision, for example if i want to write a message every 100ms, and i use
console.writeline($"{DateTime.Now:HH.mm.ss.fff}");
the time gap is never 100ms.
i have been researching a lot and i have read a lot about using a multimedia timer, so i did this.
 // Import the necessary functions from winmm.dll
 [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern uint timeSetEvent(uint uDelay, uint uResolution, TimerCallback lpTimeProc, UIntPtr dwUser, uint fuEvent);

 [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern uint timeKillEvent(uint uTimerID);

 // Import the timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod functions from winmm.dll
 [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeBeginPeriod")]
 public static extern uint MM_BeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

 [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeEndPeriod")]
 public static extern uint MM_EndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

 timerCallback1 = () => callback(checkboxindex, transferout, standardframedata, txc);
 MM_BeginPeriod(1);
 timer0ID = timeSetEvent((uint)interval, TIMER_RESOLUTION, timerCallback1, UIntPtr.Zero, EVENT_TYPE);
 MM_EndPeriod(1);

but even this didn't work and i can't find any answers, has anyone reached a 1ms precision, please share how to do it

Not 100% clear what you are asking - you need to achieve 1ms execution time? And for what purpose? Perhaps there's a different way of achieving what you're trying to do.

It's unclear, are you calling timeEndPeriod while the callback is active? If so, don't do that.

Well, since C# is a system orientated language, the system would need to interpret it. This takes longer than Object oriented languages that are compiled like C++

"I can't reach 1ms precision in C#" - that wouldn't be unexpected, actually. Clock resolution is about 15ms, if I remember correctly. Not to start about windows not being a real-time OS ...

Don't call timeEndPeriod() until you no longer need the events.  The net effect of timeBeginPeriod() is that it changes the clock interrupt frequency, that needs to stay in effect while events need to be raised.

^^ That being said, if you really need 1ms accuracy, you should investigate Real-Time OSs and/or intermediate hardware that can talk to the device within timing specs and provide a non-realtime-friendly API towards your software.

^^ and still whatever solution, the clock must have a resolution high enough.

This is typical example of XY problem: you need something, then you attempt something, it didn't worked and you ask question about attempt. Tell us what USB device it is, what you need, etc. What you are trying to achieve in winforms is not a realistic requirement.

If you need a "guaranteed" execution time then you need a real time OS first. Neither Windows nor a standard Unix in whatever flavor will do. After that you can then decide on a proper programming language. Presumably it will not be a .Net  based language.

See timeBeginPeriod for adjusting the windows tick-rate. I think this is essentially what multimedia timers do, but be aware of the drawbacks of using a higher tick-rate.

I agree with Sinatr. Likely what is truly needed by OP is to constantly stream data to a USB device.

This is the most precise method I can find to generate a timer with a resolution in the 1ms interval, IF the system supports high resolution timers.
In a simple console app on Windows 11, this is achieving approx. 99.5% of the number of expected elapsed events over a 10 sec time span, where interval=1ms, and the event handler is doing very little work and not blocking.
Performance warning: this code only demonstrates the achievable timer resolution and the timer runs in a tight loop requesting the system timestamp. There's probably more optimal implementations.
/// <summary>
/// Managed code HiRes Timer.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="interval">In milliseconds.</param>
internal class HiResTimer(int interval) : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource = new();
    private CancellationToken _runToken;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public event EventHandler? Elapsed;

    public double Interval { get; set; } = interval;

    public void Start()
    {
        _runToken = _cancelTokenSource.Token;

        Task.Run(() => {
            long freqMultiplier = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
            long oldTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

            while (true)
            {
                long newTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                if ((newTimestamp - oldTimestamp) * freqMultiplier * 0.0001 >= Interval)
                {
                    oldTimestamp = newTimestamp;
                    Elapsed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }, _runToken);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _cancelTokenSource?.Dispose();
            }
            
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

